# gbm.fit() in R language

Tags: boosting

I have a data with size of 1200 rows having binary dependent variable and around 20 independent variables which are categorical as well as continuous in nature. I have tried machine learning technique viz. Gradient boosting. I used gbm() in R. I was able to achieve 65-66% accuracy (checked through confusion matrix). I tried one more function gbm.fit() and then the model gave 94% accuracy and it predicted almost all of test data correctly. Is this correct?
Also I don't know what gbm.fit() does. I will be glad to know the difference between the above 2 functions as well.

Pardon me, i am new to machine learning.

Comment: If you don't know what gbm.fit() does, how do you know it gave you 94% accuracy?

Answer (score 2):

`gbm.fit` requires that you provide the predictor set, x, and the target variable, y. You cannot use a formula interface. My best guess for your increase in accuracy, using `gbm.fit` is that you unintentionally included the target variable in the predictor set.

Comment: +1.  That would be my guess too.  The X matrix likely contained the target by accident.